# 2X2 independent measures test + regression model

Tags: interaction, mediation

I have an experiment (4 groups) with 2 levels of 2 variables. I will also have a seperate mediation model, and I'm trying to figure out how to run the mediation model with this design.
I was thinking of it like this:

1. If the independent variable A is significant, collapse the data across the other variable, and run the mediation model.
2. If the independent variable B is significant, collapse the data across the other variable, and run the mediation model.
3. If there is a significant interaction of A x B...? What to do in this case?
   Hope this question makes sense.
   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good [discussion of mediation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_(statistics)).  My reading of it is that if A and B interact, a simple mediation model will not suffice.  In that case you might have to consider moderated mediation and/or mediated moderation.